# MySQL IFNULL question

Tags: mysql, ifnull

I have a query which contains a subquery which is something like this

```
IFNULL((SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id = 1), 'No')
```

It works OK, but I would like to return the string 'Yes' on success rather than the actual id of the row.

Is there any way to override the value it returns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
IFNULL((SELECT 'Yes' FROM mytable WHERE id = 1), 'No')
```

Answer (score 1):

Little Advance example of `IFNULL`:

**Problem**: How to get the home phone number if office phone number is not available ?

**Solution**:

```
SELECT IFNULL(office_phone_no,home_phone_no) as contact_number
FROM employee_table e
where e.username = 'sumoanand';
```